# Passing value from one class to another using property

Tags: c#, properties

I have a list i am trying to pass from one class to another. Here is the code:

```
Class1
{     
    internal Class1()
    {
        MyList = new List<string>();
    }

    //Add stuff to list
    MyList.Add("123");
    MyList.Add("234");

    public static IList<string> MyList { get; set; }                   
}

Class2
{
    var getList = Class1.MyList;
}
```

Every time i run this i am getting null value in Class2 for getList. What am i doing wrong?

Updated code which will compile:

```
Class1
{
    internal Class1()
    {
         MyList = new List<string>();
    }

    static void Main1(string[] args)
    {
         Class1 c = new Class1();
         c.MyList.Add("123");
    }

    public IList<string> MyList { get; set; }
}

namespace Test
{
    Class2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                       
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            var a = c.MyList;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code, if you elaborate we may be able to help you... You have declared the MyLIst property as static, but you are initializing it first in the constructor (instance).

What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry have not added complete code am on mobile. But purpose is to pass list of values from one class to another.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - I updated code that will compile.

Comment: @Mattis - I updated the code may be it makes sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you want, you don't need to declare a static Main function in your classes, instead initialize the instances using the constructor.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class2 instanceOfClass2 = new Class2();


    }
}

class Class1
{
    public IList<string> MyList { get; set; }

    internal Class1()
    {
        MyList = new List<string>();
        MyList.Add("123");
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        var a = c.MyList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, what I see is that you have to create an instance of your class "Class1" first in the Class2 as your List instance is created in Class1's contructor.

Just by calling Class1.MyList will not initialize "MyList" and you will always get null.

Comment: tried this it solves part of problem. I am not getting null now but still no value?

Comment: You should either create a method to add values to the MyList property, or just move the two lines into the constructor body.

 internal Class1()
    {
        MyList = new List<string>();
    //Add stuff to list
    MyList.Add("123");
    MyList.Add("234");
}